# How TOP affects SQL performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm at a bit of a loss here. I have two nearly identical queries:

```
select
    top 301
    *
from
    view
where
    columnA like '%val%'
    and
    columnB > '12/12/2019 00:00:00'
order by
    columnC
```

and

```
select
    *
from
    view
where
    columnA like '%val%'
    and
    columnB > '12/12/2019 00:00:00'
order by
    columnC
```

When I run these two queries they work fine with the date provided.
If I look back a little in history, the first query will effectively timeout my application, but the second query works fine.

I did some trouble shooting, and it appears the following must be true to time out the app.

1. top # must be included
2. order by must be on `columnC`
3. `columnB` must be sufficiently far in the past.

Due to how my application is set up, the set up for the query will always include these three elements, and I am not able to move any of these elements into the view itself, so they will always be full table scans.

I am in the process of trying to optimize my view, but I simply do not understand how adding top # to the query is causing the application to time out the way that it is.  Any help understanding how top affects SQL performance would be appreciated.

Additional Notes:

I have noticed that adding TOP does change the execution plan a little.  The largest difference I see in the two is that without top, the execution plan runs parallelism pretty much across every join, and this is not the case for the query containing top.

Comment: If `view` is a `VIEW` object, then you need to post the definition of `view` because `VIEW` objects are **composed** in queries in SQL Server and that affects query plan generation.

Comment: My first thought w.r.t. troubleshooting your problem is that your `STATISTICS` objects are stale. Have you been updating your `STATISTICS` regularly? If it's a typical LoB application then you should be updating them every day (e.g. around 3am when no-one is using your application).

Comment: Does ColumnC have index in it ? What indexes are present in the background table

Comment: Also, please post your "actual" execution plans (as opposed to your "estimated" execution plans) for each query - and post any relevant indexes.

Comment: The biggest difference is usually due to "row goals". you can add `OPTION (USE HINT('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL'))`  and see if that helps

Comment: add index for `columnB` add full text catalog and don't use `like` statement you ca use `contain` learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/… - this plan for give performance better than above query.

Comment: [Why doesn't disabling row goals give me a different query plan?](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=921#a1084) Paul did a good job there @MartinSmith.

Comment: yeah, that's a case where the hint doesn't work as not all of the cardinality effects of TOP are counted as row goals. So can try the `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@top = 987654321));` obfuscation if the hint doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, and since there's cases and should be tested, there is no static answer for a poor Q like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing in your execution plan is normal. If you check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#parallel-query-processing) you can see there are several constructs that inhibit parallelism:

- scalar UDFs
- remote query
- dynamic cursors
- recursive queries
- Multi-statement table-valued functions
- TOP keyword

So, adding a `TOP` may not look like something `big`, but it will completely change the execution plan in some cases.

Sometimes, one technique to optimize view execution is to materialize it. There are a lot of [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) again about what can exist in an indexed view, but if your view can be materialized, you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show pages with limited number of record in your application i'd suggest you use [OFFSET Fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

> 1- [T-SQL Querying: TOP and OFFSET-FETCH](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2314819&seqNum=2)
>   Source: [1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220326/reduce-query-time-for-higher-offset-in-sql-server)

Comment: How's that answering the question?

Comment: i wanted to help as i don't believe optimizing top is the answer to the bigger problem. if it's not ok i can just delete my answer

Comment: Masoud, I appreciated the answer...unfortunately there are architectural choices that sort of limit the scope of what I can and can't do.  I found something of a hacky work around in the end, and gotqn's answer helped me figure it out.